# Ionic Searchbar Doesn't Work

Tags: android, html, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I faced off a problem that I can't solve. I've searched on the web before posting this but I found nothing really useful for me.

Straight to the point. This is the problem, I have a ion-searchbar that does not receive keyboard input in Android device. I run that with ionic cordova CLI and the build was successful.

Please help me, all the other features of the app work well, I only have to fix this.

```
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchedText" [showCancelButton]="shouldShowCancel"
(ionInput)="onInput($event)" (ionClear)="onCancel($event)"></ion-searchbar>
```

That searchbar does not receive any character of my keyboard input.
If I run it on local with ionic serve it works instead.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

> I put that searchbar in ion header instead of ion content. I changed that and then it worked.